# Получение токена Яндекс Метрики по логину и паролю

Tags: php, curl, яндекс-метрика

перепробовал все, что мог, не могу получить токен Яндекс метрики - подскажите, пожалуйста.

```
<?php

$yandex_get_token_url = "https://oauth.yandex.ru/token";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $yandex_get_token_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); //посмотреть результат запроса
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'grant_type=password&username=myname&password=mypass&
client_id=9f31c5645e3647f5991edee25e7f7b31&client_secret=7dcca3a4fcdd4021b59392375e84d5d4');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$token = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $token; //Выдает {"error": "invalid_request"}

$token_o = json_decode($token);
$token = $token_o->access_token;

echo $token; //Выдает пустоту

?>
```

Это заголовок

> HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Server: gunicorn/0.13.4 Date: Thu, 29 Mar 2012 08:39:04 GMT Vary: Accept-Language Content-Type: application/json Content-Language: ru Cache-Control: no-store Set-Cookie: yandexuid=106917201333010344; Domain=.yandex.ru; expires=Tue, 29-Mar-2022 18:51:04 GMT; Max-Age=315569520; Path=/ Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Не знаю, в чем ошибка и разобраться не могу, вроде бы правильный массив post отправляю.
Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Может быть проблема в `https`? Попробуйте просто `http`.

Comment: Не помогает:

Ошибка 403

Используй HTTPS, Люк 

В интсрукции цказано использовать https

Answer (score 1):

Следующий пример возвращает адекватный результат

```
{"error": "invalid_grant"}
```

что означает `неверный логин и/или пароль`
Если подставить нормальный логин/пароль яндекс почты, то вернет нечто вроде

```
{"access_token": "31737ed4wtfe48c89omg432ca12bbc", "token_type": "bearer"}
```

То есть все нормально работает.

```
<?
$sock=fsockopen('ssl://oauth.yandex.ru', 443);
$fields="grant_type=password&username=myname&password=mypass&client_id=9f31c5645e3647f5991edee25e7f7b31&client_secret=7dcca3a4fcdd4021b59392375e84d5d4";
$msg="POST /token HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: oauth.yandex.ru\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nContent-Length: ".(strlen($fields))."\r\n\r\n".$fields."\r\n\r\n";
fwrite($sock, $msg);
$resp='';
while (!feof($sock)) {
       $resp.=fgets($sock, 128);
};
fclose($sock);
$arr=Array();
preg_match_all("/{.*?}/", $resp, $arr);
$json=json_decode($arr[0][0]);
var_dump($json);
?>
```

Comment: @maxsonic добавил. Примерно так можно извлечь данные.

Comment: Вот так извлек

    $token= fgets($sock, 128);
    $token_o = json_decode($token);
    $token = $token_o->access_token;

Огромное спасибо за помощь)))
Вы очень помогли.

Comment: Не за что :)